# Flutter StreamBuilder with initialData and null-awareness

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I have some problems understanding the StreamBuilder using the new null-aware operators.

As a learning project I am implementing a sign-in flow with the BloC pattern. For my email sign-in form I have created a model class which I access through a StreamBuilder. Without the use of initialData it makes complete sense that snapshot.data can be null. However, setting the initialData to a predefined empty model, snapshot.data could never be null right? Here is my code snippet:

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<EmailSignInModel>(
        stream: widget.bloc.modelStream,
        initialData: EmailSignInModel(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final EmailSignInModel model = snapshot.data;
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: _buildChildren(),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

The compiler warns me that snapshot.data is of type <EmailSignModel?> which is not equal to . I could fix this with `snapshot.data ?? EmailSignModel()` but this would be redundant with initialData right?

What is the proper way of handling this situation and taken care of the null-awareness of Dart?

Comment: Just wanted to say this is a very interesting question. The fact is that AsyncSnapshot<T> will have a getter data of type T?, so nullability is baked into the AsyncSnapshot class. Maybe this should be reported in the Flutter Github? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues

Comment: I went to have a look in the source code and saw they had a solution to this. Answered below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diving into the source code, I found the following:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart

```
  /// The latest data received by the asynchronous computation.
  ///
  /// If this is non-null, [hasData] will be true.
  ///
  /// If [error] is not null, this will be null. See [hasError].
  ///
  /// If the asynchronous computation has never returned a value, this may be
  /// set to an initial data value specified by the relevant widget. See
  /// [FutureBuilder.initialData] and [StreamBuilder.initialData].
  final T? data;

  /// Returns latest data received, failing if there is no data.
  ///
  /// Throws [error], if [hasError]. Throws [StateError], if neither [hasData]
  /// nor [hasError].
  T get requireData {
    if (hasData)
      return data!;
    if (hasError)
      throw error!;
    throw StateError('Snapshot has neither data nor error');
  }
```

`AsyncSnapshot` actually has a `requireData` getter, which will ensure non-null or will throw an error. So just replace `snapshot.data` with `snapshot.requireData`

This still requires some manual work where the use of `initialData` and `requireData` need to be kept in sync. You could also just use `snapshot.data!` which basically does the same.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Funny that I was just one ctrl-click away from the doc-string showing part of the answer.

All with all, using initialData cannot be null and using requireData is a neat solution. I also like the simple use of ! directly as it is always close to the initialData parameter and making clear it cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

I just replace the `snapshot.data!` with `snapshot.requireData`